# Not able to navigate to RabbitMQ management console

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

If I run as service I can't able to navigate to RabbitMQ management console.

http://localhost:15672

But if I execute "rabbitmq-server start" in the comment prompt, means I can able to login to RabbitMQ management console and also I can able to see the queue details.

Basic Info:  Running in Windows OS(32 bit) , rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management using this comment i trying to enable the managemenet console but its saying as "Plugin configuration unchanged", RabbitMQ version: 3.3.5(32 bit) Erlang Version : 7.0

Comment: please update your question with more specifics: are you running windows, linux, macosx or ??? what configuration are you using when running as a service? what account is it running as? what do the rabbitmq log files say, when running as a service? lastly: pleast ask a specific question instead of just making statements.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response derick... Solution is.... I opened Comment prompt using administration privilege and gave comment to enable the management console... After that I can able see the management console In my browser...